# Correlation failed. - Azure AD B2C not able to connect and validate Auth0 users

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, auth0, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am adding Auth0 as one of the IDPs in Azure ADB2C via custom policies. I have added Auth0(OpenId connect) technical profile like below in custom policies, however, when a user tries to log in, I am getting `Correlation failed.` Error.

[image]

I am unsure what else needs to be done to successfully add Auth0 as one of the IDPs in Azure AdB2c. The error I am getting is

[image]

Appreciate any help.

Edit: Since output windows show the below warning, this could be related to the cookie setting that I have. The warning in output window is

```
OriginalFormat":"'{CorrelationCookieName}' cookie not found.","CorrelationCookieName":".AspNetCore.Correlation.SQ39Fi0_vaGlg66ahnE4M7TulHA4lObhlTIV4QmSrBQ"}
```

My cookie setting in the application is like:

```
 services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
     { 
         options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None; 
     });
```

and I using it like below:

```
 app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
 {
     Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.None
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This error derives from a [password reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#password-reset-policy-legacy).

"If the self-service password reset experience isn't enabled, selecting this link doesn't automatically trigger a password reset user flow. Instead, the error code AADB2C90118 is returned to your application. Your application must handle this error code by reinitializing the authentication library to authenticate an Azure AD B2C password reset user flow."

Comment: This error is occurring while the user is trying to log in using Auth0 as IDP. Auth0 logs show successful login, but looks like Azure AD B2C is not able to handle the token provided by Auth0 or there may be something missing in-between Auth0 and Azure AD B2C.

Comment: In the error logs, I see the below error but the metadata URL is public and I can access and see metadata on that URL.  "Kind": "FatalException", "Content": { "Time": "4:53 AM", "Exception": { "Kind": "Handled", "HResult": "80131500", "Message": "The metadata specified for the identity provider does not contain an IDPSSODescriptor.", "Data": { "IsPolicySpecificError": false } }

Comment: IDPSSODescriptor is for a SAML connection. You are trying to use OIDC. Did you perhaps configure Auth0 for SAML?

Comment: The above message is when I try with SAML, I tried to configure Auth0 using OIDC and SAML too, but none worked. Output window for "Correlation Failed" error using OIDC shows something like this - OriginalFormat":"'{CorrelationCookieName}' cookie not found.","CorrelationCookieName":".AspNetCore.Correlation.SQ39Fi0_vaGlg66ahnE4M7TulHA4lObhlTIV4QmSrBQ"}. Could be something how cookies are configured.